# save datetime value 12 in Oracle database

Tags: oracle11g

When I try to insert datetime value 12:58 AM into the oracle table it gets inserted as 00:58. How can I insert datetime value as 12 in my oracle db? I've set my Oracle time format as 24 hr time. Any suggestions would help.

[image]

Insert statement :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
(
DATE_CREATED,
PLANNED_START,
PLANNED_COMPLETION
)
VALUES
(
sysdate,
TO_CHAR(p_planned_Start_Date, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
TO_CHAR(end_date_, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')      
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the 24-hour time, you need to use `HH24` instead of `HH`.

For the 12-hour time, the AM/PM indicator is written as `A.M.` (if you want periods in the result) or `AM` (if you don't). For example:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (LD_DATE) Values (TO_DATE('08/30/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY '));
```

And select it as below:

```
SELECT LD_DATE,
       TO_CHAR(LD_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "Date 24Hr",
       TO_CHAR(LD_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') "Date 12Hr"
  FROM test
;
```

Comment: I've my database nls format set to format "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS". Do I have to use To_date on insert to set the format again?

Comment: You need to use to_char() like i have used above.

Comment: I did use as per your suggestion it's now failing to insert  . TO_CHAR(p_planned_Start_Date, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
 TO_CHAR(end_date_, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),

Comment: Can you share your table column structure and your insert script. Lets see how it fails.

Comment: I've shared my table structure and insert statement in my above question.